# Navigate through my forms like a webpage in c#

Tags: c#, navigation, multiple-forms

Just like the title says, I want to navigate through my forms as if i were on a website.
For now I have 2 forms with both a individual design. Ive changed the name of my 1st form to Home and my second form to Inventory.
To get from Home to Inventory i have tryed this code in my picturebox click event

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.Show();
```

INstead of showing me the inventory form, it creates a new blank form..
So this didnt work out for me, or i dont know how to properly use it.

Could someone help me out?

Comment: Tried with the name Inventory ?

Comment: If you changed the form name to inventory why are you showing form2?

Comment: I would use two different Panels and dock each to fill the complete Form. Then you can use panel1.Hide() and panel2.Show().

Comment: Why did i not come up with the panels.. Thank you very much! This will do just fine :)

Comment: Use WPF Pages inside a Frame.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the name as `Inventory` of the second form then use that name

```
Inventory inventory = new Inventory();
inventory.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use WinForms.. use WPF. WPF has built in functionality for Navigation.

This should get you started (on navigation that is):

[MSDN - Navigation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx)